# Set Project Location - Already Contains a Project

Tags: visual-studio-2003, iis-5

I have a .NET 1.1 solution I'm opening in VS2003. One of the Projects is a Webservice, which points to a page on localhost. On the computer that created the solution it is able to open it and works just fine. When opened on any other computer, I get prompted:

> Set Project Location - ProjectName
> Select the location of the working copy of your web projects. You can either accept the default location or change it by clicking in the cell and editing it.
>
> The visual studio location will be at d:\[...] as specified in the previous dialog box.

There was no previous dialog box. Additionally, the "Enter working copy location here" needs to point to the IIS location where the project is located, but it wants to create a new one with a _1 at the end.

I suppose I could understand a technical limitation of VS2003 needing to attach to local IIS, but why would it work fine on the machine on which it was created?

Further, the software contained therein is coded to look for files in specific places, as provided in the .config file. These files need to be in the same location on my machine as on the Build machine, and this was working fine when the project was not part of a Solution.

As I understand it all VS2003 needs to do to that project is create a /bin/ folder and drop the assemblies in it.

Why can it do that as-is sometimes but not other times?
How can I tell VS2003 to point to the same location as the existing files?

VS2003
.NET 1.1
IIS 5 / WinXP SP3

Comment: I am having the same issue... was a solution for this ever discovered?

Comment: Kinda... I hit OK and let it put the built versions in the _1 location.  Then, when I do another get, I have to remove the Projects from the solution and re-add them. Ghetto, but it works.